# How to pass a different config file while running sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

When in sbt, is it possible to pass a different config file to use?

```
sbt run
```

That will use the default config file application.conf

I want to be able to toggle between different config files during development, how can I pass this as a argument while inside of sbt.

Comment: If you mean passing the parameter before running sbt, that would be `sbt "run -Dconfig.resource=application.test.conf"`. If you mean while you are in sbt console, I'd have to dig more..

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `-D` flag to override any specific property you want inside your configuration files. This has been available since version 1.0.1 afaik. Example:

`sbt run -D akka.cluster.seed-nodes=["akka.tcp://TestApp@host1:2552", "akka.tcp://TestApp@host2:2552"]`

This would replace whatever value `application.conf` holds for:

```
akka {
  cluster {
    seed-nodes = ["", "", /// etc]
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to override the whole config, do something like this:

```
val runtimeMxBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean
val arguments = runtimeMxBean.getInputArguments.asScala.toList

val config = arguments.find(_.contains("config.path")) match {
  case Some(value) => {
   val opt = value.split("=")
   if (Files.exists(opt.last)) {
     ConfigFactory.load(opt.last)
   } else {
     ConfigFactory.load("application.conf")
   }
  case None => ConfigFactory.load("application.conf")
}
```

- Pass the file path do your config file using -D, such as `config.path=...`.
- When you load the configuration, you need to do something like check if there is a runtime argument provided which specifies the file path, check if the file exists, and load that file instead.

Update: Option 3: Use `config.resource`

You can override the whole config file with `-Dconfig.resource=filepath`, if you ever need to load a completely separate one.

**Option 4**

You can also override specific values of config options with environment variables. It looks like this:

```
database {
  host = "localhost"
  host = ${?DATABASE_HOST}
}
```

This means if a `DATABASE_HOST` env variable is set, its value will be used to override whatever `application.conf` already holds for that key.

Answer (score 1):

Also can use `-D` to add the external `resources` folder in `sbt`, example(add into **build.sbt**, if use module, this should be added into module too):

```
val myResourceDirectory = Option(System.getProperty("myResourceDirectory")).getOrElse("hello_world")
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value / myResourceDirectory
```

add specific `myResourceDirectory` into `unmanagedResourceDirectories`,  so the usage maybe like:

```
sbt -DmyResourceDirectory=myfolder/local //local
sbt -DmyResourceDirectory=myfolder/dev //dev
sbt -DmyResourceDirectory=myfolder/prod //prod
```

Comment: what do you mean if I use module?

Comment: @Blankman, my mean if you use submodule in your project, and you also want to apply `myResourceDirectory` in your submodule, you need to add `unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value / myResourceDirectory` in your submodule settings too.